# How to add a new textView to empty TextView array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have this array

```
 val textViewList = arrayListOf<TextView>()
```

and I want to add a new textView with code

```
 textViewList.add(TextView)
```

to do that

```
  textViewList[0].textSize = 20f
  textViewList[0].text = "Programmatically created textView "
  myLayout.addView(textViewList[0])
```

but

```
textViewList.add(TextView)
```

is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some try and error but this

```
  textViewList.add(TextView(this))
```

worked.

Comment: I am new to this Kotlin what is "this"?